# Como faço para incorporar uma pagina HTML dentro de outra sem iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho uma pagina comum porém dentro de body em uma div quero por uma `li` ou um `p` de outro html, assim eu tenho uma página main caso eu precise fazer alterações e tenho conteúdos externos. Sem precisar mudar todas as páginas quando eu for inserir um novo link no menu, por exemplo. li sobre o  e o import na tag link mas não consegui por. alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Geralmente os frameworks web te dão essa opção quando você usa alguma linguagem de programação server-side. Você pretende usar alguma ou quer simular isso com JavaScript? Aliás, com Angular isso também é simples, com jQuery e outros eu já não sei.

Comment: Porque não podes usar iframe?

Comment: @Genos pq fica dentro de um quadro, não fica tão responsivo. ou não sei fazer ficar tão bom quanto direto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Guilherme,

você pode usar a função load() do jQuery

```
$( "#ul" ).load( "pagina-com-o-ul-modificado #ul-menu" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

E como o JBueno disse, existem diversas frameworks que possuem suporte pra isso, vai depender da linguagem que você vai usar.

Comment: Isso resolve. ^^ muito obrigado, ajudou imensamente!